# Excel copy data from one sheet to another based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from one sheet to another if a condition has been fulfilled.

I'll try and be as detailed as possible:

I have **sheet 1** which contains the following

```
Date (example 06/04/2016) 
Gross (example 54.99)
Net (example 52.92)
Item URL (example http://example.co.uk/test/random-mumbo-jumbo/item=123456789)
```

I have **sheet 2** which contains the following

```
Date (example 6-Apr-2016)
Item number (example 123456789)
Amount Received 1 (empty)
Amount Received 2 (empty)
```

What I would like to do is in sheet 2, if the date matches and the item number is found at the end of the Item URL in sheet 1 then copy the Net and Gross values over to Amount Received 1 and Amount Received 2.

There may be cases where an item number and date come up multiple times.

Any ideas if this is possible? If so any hints or tips on how to get this done?

I would really appreciate any help (would save me tons and tons of time!)

Comment: First, you can use a helper column to pull the end of the URL out, so you only have that.  (You could use a few different formulas, from `Right()`, to `Mid()` with a `Search()` in there). Then, you could use a [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) to look up a date and item number, and return the Net and Gross Values.  What have you tried? If the date *and* item number repeat, but have different expected outputs, you may want to consider a third variable to use if you have it. ...or some other condition.

Comment: Questions asking for a code solution (tagged as excel-vba, for instance) which do not show any code or even attempts at code/pseudo code are pretty much explicitly off-topic here. Do you know *any* VBA? Have you tried *anything*? Even a failed attempt is a demonstration of your effort in good faith, and that goes a long way to show you are not a help vampire.

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, nice name by the way! To be honest I haven't tried too much as I really did not know how to format the condition, I can do simple ones based on one thing but not something of this calibre. I can try and extract the item numbers from the end as you mentioned. 

Say I did get that done, where would I go from there? 

Thanks for reaching out :)

Comment: Hi David, Sorry the tag came up and I thought maybe it would need VBA as it seems a bit more complicated than what I'm used to.

Comment: If you can get the item number, what do you think you *should* try and do with that?  Trying to walk you through the logic/steps here...

Comment: Hi David, perhaps... Try and write a condition which finds duplicates between both sheets as well as a date match using the & logic?

Comment: Sorry can't help you. You don't seem to have any understanding of even Excel formula let alone VBA which may be required to solve this problem. My suggestion is to break this in to several steps. Try to solve them one at a time. Once you do that, try to put them all together. If you can't, then revise or edit your question showing your progress. It will be much easier to help you that way.

Comment: Hi David, ok I'll prove you wrong and will post up a solution :)

Comment: Hi David, posted the solution. Hope it helps you as you could not help me. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is a solution to the problem.

Step 1 - Concatenate the date and ripped item number in the sheet using formula

```
=B2&"-"&RIGHT(E2,12) (as the item number is always 12 digits long)
```

Step 2 - Do the same on the other sheet - no ripping of the item number needed as we have a clean item number here to begin with

```
=G2&"-"&F2
```

Step 3 (filling in the net) - Used VLOOKUP to match the concatenated figures between both sheets - pulling out values from index value of 3 which referred to my net figures

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,Sheet2!A:D,3,FALSE),0)
```

Step 4 (filling in the gross) - Used VLOOKUP to match the concatenated figures between both sheets - pulling out values from the index of value 4 which referred to my net figures

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE),0)
```

Hope this helps anyone - the concatenated columns in the excel sheets can be hidden if needed, makes matching simpler this way!